# How to find checked RadioButton inside Repeater Item?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, repeater, radio-button

I have a Repeater control on ASPX-page defined like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="answerVariantRepeater" runat="server"
    onitemdatabound="answerVariantRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="answerVariantRadioButton" runat="server"
            GroupName="answerVariants" 
            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%>'"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

To allow select only one radio button in time I have used a trick form [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12371/).

But now when form is submitted I want to determine which radio button is checked.

I could do this:

```
RadioButton checkedButton = null;

foreach (RepeaterItem item in answerVariantRepeater.Items)
{
    RadioButton control=(RadioButton)item.FindControl("answerVariantRadioButton");
    if (control.Checked)
    {
        checkedButton = control;
        break;
    }
}
```

but hope it could be done somehow simplier (maybe via LINQ to objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You are using javascript already to handle the radio button click event on the client, you could update a hidden field with the selected value at the same time.

Your server code would then just access the selected value from the hidden field.

Comment: Either the original solution in your question or this will work nicely.

Answer (score 7):

You could always use [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) to get the submitted radio button:

```
var value = Request.Form["answerVariants"];
```

I think the submitted value defaults to the id of the `<asp:RadioButton />` that was selected, but you can always add a value attribute - even though it's not officially an `<asp:RadioButton />` property - and this will then be the submitted value:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="answerVariantRadioButton" runat="server"
    GroupName="answerVariants" 
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%>'"
    value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomethingToUseAsTheValue")%>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the only thing you could use LINQ to Objects for here would be to take the conditions from within the foreach loop and move them to a where clause.

```
RadioButton checked = 
    (from item in answerVariantRepeater.Items
    let radioButton = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("answerVariantRadioButton")
    where radioButton.Checked
    select radioButton).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Maybe it's possible to avoid using both Items and FindControl in favor of some Controls collection.

Comment: I've never seen a different way to get an instance of a control from a templated parent control.

The simplest thing would be to use a RadioButtonList, but I assume that your example was simplified for clarity and there were other controls in the template that prevented you from using that.