# to find the value of the radio button checked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

hi I have a radio button list inside a repeater , the repeater is inside a Datalist.i need to get the value of the selected radio button. Also I need to select  only a single radio in entire datalist using javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290018/how-to-find-checked-radiobutton-inside-repeater-item

Comment: if you want to get the checked value server side you should use FindControl for the specific DataListItem, if you want to do it ClientSide it's a bit harder but you could do it with jQuery, it depends really on the ASPX structure of your DataList and items in it.

Comment: It is poor GUI to have 1 radio. Instead use a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with pure client side JavaScript regardless of Repeater, DataList or anything.

Have this code in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedRadioButtonValue(strGroupName) {
    var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oCurInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oCurInput.type == "radio" && oCurInput.name == strGroupName && oCurInput.checked)
            return oCurInput.value;
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
```

Then to get the selected value call the function passing the `name` of the radio buttons group - all radio buttons with same name considered a group and the browser will let the user select only one of these.

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/BL9xJ/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the normal HTML Radio Button control. Everything else is pretty complicated.

Then you can use the following code to figure out which one is selected:

http://remy.supertext.ch/2008/02/find-checked-radio-button-in-aspnet/