# How to check which radio button is checked in data list?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get which radio button is checked in the data list and that radio button value using javascript or c#.

i have code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyField="Qno" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <EditItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            Qno:
            <asp:Label ID="QnoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qno") %>' />
            <br />
            Question:
            <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
            <br />
            Ans1:
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="gp" Text='<%# Eval("Ans1") %>' runat="server" />
            <br />
            Ans2:
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" GroupName="gp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans2") %>' />
            <br />
            Ans3:
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" GroupName="gp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans3") %>' />
            <br />
            Ans4:
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" GroupName="gp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ans4") %>' />
            <br />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
        <SeparatorStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" 
            Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedRadioButtonValue(strGroupName) {
    var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oCurInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oCurInput.type == "radio" && oCurInput.name == strGroupName && oCurInput.checked)
            return oCurInput.value;
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
```

Call it like

```
GetSelectedRadioButtonValue('gp')
```

refer [to find the value of the radio button checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067096/to-find-the-value-of-the-radio-button-checked)

Comment: How to get one one rows radio button value from data list suppose example i want the value of checked radio button that is from row number 2 or 3 like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedRadioButtonValue(strGroupName) {
    var arrInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oCurInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oCurInput.type == "radio" && oCurInput.name == strGroupName && oCurInput.checked)
            return oCurInput.value;
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a javascript solution, but *for anyone else who are happy to use JQuery* `$("input[name=g]:checked").val()​` where 'g' is the group name would be a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
{
     foreach (DataListItem item in DataList.Items)
                {
                    RadioButtonList RB = item.FindControl("RB") as RadioButtonList;
                    if(RB!=null && RB.SelectedValue!=null)
                {
                    Label1.text=RB.SelectedValue //for testing purpose only
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

on the itembound event of Datalist try the following code

```
RadioButton rdbtn= e.Item.FindControl("RadioButton1") as RadioButton;
var chkstring = rdbtn.Checked;
```

you would get the value whether it is checked or not
and similarly it